# How can we prevent from multiple builds with a Maven project on IntelliJ IDE

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

We have a Maven multiproject and don't have any good solution working with Intellij without wasting time waiting unuseful re-builds.
IntelliJ loses the benefits of its powerful incremental compiler - we observe that can't work properly with Maven because forcing the developers waiting for 2 builds before the server starts in debug mode (one time with Maven and a second time for IntelliJ internal compile).

Before Maven, the 'Hammer' was the only button to click. And it was done automatically when starting the server. Moreover, only the changed code was compiled thanks to the powerful incremental compilation process of IntelliJ.

The "Hammer" build is still needed in order IntelliJ syncs its indexes and hot debugs.

Now a Maven Project, after mvn clean install - IntelliJ MUST COMPILE A SECOND TIME (the hammer tool) when starting the server - otherwise, the hot debug doesn't work. With the standard launch config in previous image, the build stats automatically before the server starts
It sounds that there is no link between classes created via the Maven process and the IntelliJ Index - so IntelliJ must re-compile - no choice.

Most of the time, IntelliJ asks to its internal compile to recompile everything / can't say the rule.
Actually it sounds like IntelliJ recompiles the whole module impacted and all child dependencies - just like Maven does. So if you update the dependencies of the root module or change some classes of the root module, IntelliJ recompiles every modules - most of times.

So the fairy tale of IntelliJ's incremental compilation is very far away now with Maven.

Now in the latest 2019.3 IntelliJ proposed the famous "Delegate IDE build/actions to Maven" Settings.
It has been stated that some bug was resolved with 2019.3.1.

But now if we choose the option Delegate IDE build/actions to Maven,:
A standard launch config, will launch the Tomcat Server and parallel ... 2 Maven builds (Wow!): 1 for the single war module and another for the parent containing all the multimodule.
Even worse, IntelliJ starts after a while several duplicate processes of the parent multimodule, just like it restarts in parallel.

Please note that our project builds perfectly on Maven / Bamboo CI, and that IntelliJ is OK without this new option.

Question was : 
How can we prevent from multiple builds with a Maven project on IntelliJ IDE?
What are the settings for working peacefully with a powerful IDE ?

Any hints welcome

Answer (score 0):

> But now if we choose the option Delegate IDE build/actions to Maven,: A standard launch config, will launch the Tomcat Server and parallel ... 2 Maven builds (Wow!)

There was a bug: [IDEA-228164](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228164) Fixed in 2019.3.2 version please update from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

> Actually it sounds like IntelliJ recompiles the whole module impacted and all child dependencies - just like Maven does

Try to disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Use Maven output directories** re-import project in Maven tool awindow and Build | Rebuild Project?

Comment: Well 2019.3.2 hasn't been released. In the ticket you mention they are talking about 2019.3.1 version. In IDEA-224676 they state that it should be fixed in 2019.3.1.

Comment: Are you proposing not to use Maven /target directories for the IntelliJ compiler? I'll have a try but that sounds weird...

Comment: With Delegate IDE build/actions to Maven + Unchecking "Use Maven output directories" 
- prevents from starting the server in parallel during the build
- BUT starts an entire project build - event if everything has already been compiled previously. With 2 multimodules in the workspace, that means 2 mvn install in parallel of both project - Jet Brains has no idea of the dependencies of the 2 multimodules but it builds both of them in parallel - just to be shure.

Comment: Now - I undertand that the option Delegate IDE build/actions to Maven  is buggy and cannot be used - and maybe isn't useful at all. what I need is probably your suggestion - only unchecking "Use Maven output directories". I have to watch out what happen changing generated classes or the multimodule structure / dependencies .